# chrome extension stop working and not work in background

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I created chrome extension that notify the user on the top news from some sites I want to run it the background so I write this in **manifest.json**:

```
"background": {
"scripts": ["js/jquery.js", "js/background.js"],
"persistent": true
 }
```

and in the **background.js**:

```
window.setTimeout(checkNew, 60000);
function checkNew() {
// do some thing here [Ex: ajax requests...] and notifications api ...etc
setTimeout(checkNew, 200000);
}
```

however the extension work well for sometime but suddenly it stop
and it did not work in the background although I give it background permission

I searched alot but I did not find the right answer for me.

**[Edit]**

I found the error I have syntax Error in my code thanks for all sorry because I asked without checking my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Impossible to tell without the rest of your program, but I'd wager some error happens in your code that stops execution before it reaches the new `setTimeout`.

1. Try to move `setTimeout` at the top of `checkNew`: that way, even if some exception happens that stops the flow, the next execution is already scheduled.
2. Debug! Check the background page's console for errors.

Answer (score -2):

Along with **persistent: true** in 'background' , you also need to add permissions for background.

```
"permissions": [
    "background"
],
```

Comment: Not true at all. That permission only dictates what happens if Chrome is closed. As long as Chrome is open (and when it reopens), the code in the question should work (barring errors).